# Gauging $R$-Symmetry

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-invariance, supergravity

I know that if one gauges the supersymmetry group, you get supergravity. You can then further gauge the $R$-symmetry and these are the so-called gauged supergravities. But I don't think I've seen anyone gauge the $R$-symmetry in a theory with global supersymmetry (ie, just a supersymmetric field theory but not supergravity). So my question is: Can this be done?  If not, what is the problem with only gauging the $R$-symmetry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer, but the $U(1)$ R-symmetry cannot be gauged in global SUSY. This can be seen from the fact that it rotates the fermionic coordinates $\theta$, which are independent of spacetime coordinates in global SUSY. If you gauge the R-symmetry, the transformation of $\theta$ becomes local, and $\theta$ becomes spacetime dependent -- this means you have curved superspace, i.e. supergravity.